# Javascript array display

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript and decided to create my own JS quiz.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    score = 0;
    var questions = [['whats 2 + 2' , '4'] , ['whats 3 * 3' , 9] , ['whats 2 * 7' , 14] ];

    function askQ(ans){
        var answer =prompt (questions[i] , '');
        if(answer == questions[1]){
            score++;
            alert('Yahooo , ur right');
        } else{
            alert('Brush up ur GK');
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length ; i++) {
        askQ(questions[i]);
    };
    </script>
```

The problem is when the question "prompted" to the users screen, the answer is also displayed simultaneousl , eg . for the 1st question this is what appears:

"what is 2+2,4" .. now you see , "4" is the answer

I  am sure in order for the 4 not to display I need to do something differently, so I went through a few online snippets of code and it was either too complex for me to understand.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/Lsuhejf1/).

Comment: `questions[i]` is an array consisting of two elements. you want to display  `questions[i][0]` in the prompt, and compare the answer to `questions[i][1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you're passing in `ans` into the function (which conveniently contains the question and answer pair), but you're not actually *using* that anywhere.

The line:

```
var answer =prompt (questions[i] , '');
```

Should probably be:

```
var answer = prompt(ans[0], ''); // Display the question
```

And the line:

```
if(answer == questions[1]){
```

Should probably be:

```
if(answer == ans[1]) { // Compare answer to correct answer
```

Also, it might be better to store all your answers as strings rather than numbers, since you're comparing them to strings entered by the user.  `['whats 3 * 3' , 9]` should be `['whats 3 * 3' , '9']`

A better design also might be to use JavaScript object literals to store the question/answer pairs.  Something like:

```
var questions = [
  {Question: 'whats 2 + 2', Answer: '4'},
  {Question: 'whats 3 * 3', Answer: '9'},
  {Question: 'whats 2 * 7', Answer: '14'}
];
```

Then, you can change your code to:

```
var answer = prompt(ans.Question, ''); // Display the question
```

And:

```
if(answer == ans.Answer) { // Compare answer to correct answer
```

This is a bit easier to read.

Comment: thats a really intelligent way of doing it mike , i mean the last part of your answer , where you do "var answer = prompt(ans.Question, '');"  , and By the way yes , as of now , even if you answer the question "what is 2+2" as 4 , it will mark it as wrong , because from the prompt the value accepted is a "String" whereas whats in the array is a "Int" (Not sure ! but i think thats right) , You suggest Mike that i turn the "Ints" in the array to strings , but what i'd actually like is once the user enters the answer in the prompt , i would like to convert it to a Int .

Comment: You can convert their answer to an int using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).  You'd want to implement some sort of error checking code in case they don't enter a valid number.

Comment: it works now fine , not yet implemented your suggestion of checking if the user enters something other than a number . and it works without using the parseInt . heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/Lsuhejf1/2/

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  score = 0;
var questions = [['whats 2 + 2' , '4'] , ['whats 3 * 3' , 9] , ['whats 2 * 7' , 14] ];

function askQ(ans){
    var answer =prompt (ans[0] , '');
    if(answer == ans[1]){
        score++;
        alert('Yahooo , ur right');
    } else{
        alert('Brush up ur GK');
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length ; i++) {
    askQ(questions[i]);
};
</script>
```

Here are the main differences:
Instead of

```
var answer =prompt (questions[0] , '');
```

I did

```
var answer =prompt (ans[0] , '');
```

Because you have to actually use the passed argument ans with its first value.

Instead of

```
if(answer == questions[1]){
```

I did

```
if(answer == ans[1]){
```

For the same reason as above but with its second value.

Comment: What is different between this and OP's code? "Teach a man to fish..."